# Hibernate performing unlimited queries on findAll()

Tags: java, hibernate

I tried to setup a bidirectional `@OneToMany` relationship (One airline has many applications) when running `airlineRepository.findAll()` instead of one select all query hibernate does this forever and crashes the application:

```
Hibernate: select submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_1_, submitteda0_.airline_id as airline_2_1_1_, submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_1_, airline1_.id as id1_0_2_, airline1_.description as descript2_0_2_, airline1_.title as title3_0_2_ from applications submitteda0_ left outer join airlines airline1_ on submitteda0_.airline_id=airline1_.id where submitteda0_.user_id=?
Hibernate: select submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_1_, submitteda0_.airline_id as airline_2_1_1_, submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_1_, airline1_.id as id1_0_2_, airline1_.description as descript2_0_2_, airline1_.title as title3_0_2_ from applications submitteda0_ left outer join airlines airline1_ on submitteda0_.airline_id=airline1_.id where submitteda0_.user_id=?
Hibernate: select submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_1_, submitteda0_.airline_id as airline_2_1_1_, submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_1_, airline1_.id as id1_0_2_, airline1_.description as descript2_0_2_, airline1_.title as title3_0_2_ from applications submitteda0_ left outer join airlines airline1_ on submitteda0_.airline_id=airline1_.id where submitteda0_.user_id=?
Hibernate: select submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_1_, submitteda0_.airline_id as airline_2_1_1_, submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_1_, airline1_.id as id1_0_2_, airline1_.description as descript2_0_2_, airline1_.title as title3_0_2_ from applications submitteda0_ left outer join airlines airline1_ on submitteda0_.airline_id=airline1_.id where submitteda0_.user_id=?
Hibernate: select submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_1_, submitteda0_.airline_id as airline_2_1_1_, submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_1_, airline1_.id as id1_0_2_, airline1_.description as descript2_0_2_, airline1_.title as title3_0_2_ from applications submitteda0_ left outer join airlines airline1_ on submitteda0_.airline_id=airline1_.id where submitteda0_.user_id=?
Hibernate: select submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_1_, submitteda0_.airline_id as airline_2_1_1_, submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_1_, airline1_.id as id1_0_2_, airline1_.description as descript2_0_2_, airline1_.title as title3_0_2_ from applications submitteda0_ left outer join airlines airline1_ on submitteda0_.airline_id=airline1_.id where submitteda0_.user_id=?
Hibernate: select submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_1_, submitteda0_.airline_id as airline_2_1_1_, submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_1_, airline1_.id as id1_0_2_, airline1_.description as descript2_0_2_, airline1_.title as title3_0_2_ from applications submitteda0_ left outer join airlines airline1_ on submitteda0_.airline_id=airline1_.id where submitteda0_.user_id=?
Hibernate: select submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_1_, submitteda0_.airline_id as airline_2_1_1_, submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_1_, airline1_.id as id1_0_2_, airline1_.description as descript2_0_2_, airline1_.title as title3_0_2_ from applications submitteda0_ left outer join airlines airline1_ on submitteda0_.airline_id=airline1_.id where submitteda0_.user_id=?
Hibernate: select submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_1_, submitteda0_.airline_id as airline_2_1_1_, submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_1_, airline1_.id as id1_0_2_, airline1_.description as descript2_0_2_, airline1_.title as title3_0_2_ from applications submitteda0_ left outer join airlines airline1_ on submitteda0_.airline_id=airline1_.id where submitteda0_.user_id=?
Hibernate: select submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_1_, submitteda0_.airline_id as airline_2_1_1_, submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_1_, airline1_.id as id1_0_2_, airline1_.description as descript2_0_2_, airline1_.title as title3_0_2_ from applications submitteda0_ left outer join airlines airline1_ on submitteda0_.airline_id=airline1_.id where submitteda0_.user_id=?
Hibernate: select submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_1_, submitteda0_.airline_id as airline_2_1_1_, submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_1_, airline1_.id as id1_0_2_, airline1_.description as descript2_0_2_, airline1_.title as title3_0_2_ from applications submitteda0_ left outer join airlines airline1_ on submitteda0_.airline_id=airline1_.id where submitteda0_.user_id=?
Hibernate: select submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_1_, submitteda0_.airline_id as airline_2_1_1_, submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_1_, airline1_.id as id1_0_2_, airline1_.description as descript2_0_2_, airline1_.title as title3_0_2_ from applications submitteda0_ left outer join airlines airline1_ on submitteda0_.airline_id=airline1_.id where submitteda0_.user_id=?
Hibernate: select submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_1_, submitteda0_.airline_id as airline_2_1_1_, submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_1_, airline1_.id as id1_0_2_, airline1_.description as descript2_0_2_, airline1_.title as title3_0_2_ from applications submitteda0_ left outer join airlines airline1_ on submitteda0_.airline_id=airline1_.id where submitteda0_.user_id=?
Hibernate: select submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_1_, submitteda0_.airline_id as airline_2_1_1_, submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_1_, airline1_.id as id1_0_2_, airline1_.description as descript2_0_2_, airline1_.title as title3_0_2_ from applications submitteda0_ left outer join airlines airline1_ on submitteda0_.airline_id=airline1_.id where submitteda0_.user_id=?
Hibernate: select submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_1_, submitteda0_.airline_id as airline_2_1_1_, submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_1_, airline1_.id as id1_0_2_, airline1_.description as descript2_0_2_, airline1_.title as title3_0_2_ from applications submitteda0_ left outer join airlines airline1_ on submitteda0_.airline_id=airline1_.id where submitteda0_.user_id=?
Hibernate: select submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_1_, submitteda0_.airline_id as airline_2_1_1_, submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_1_, airline1_.id as id1_0_2_, airline1_.description as descript2_0_2_, airline1_.title as title3_0_2_ from applications submitteda0_ left outer join airlines airline1_ on submitteda0_.airline_id=airline1_.id where submitteda0_.user_id=?
Hibernate: select submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_1_, submitteda0_.airline_id as airline_2_1_1_, submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_1_, airline1_.id as id1_0_2_, airline1_.description as descript2_0_2_, airline1_.title as title3_0_2_ from applications submitteda0_ left outer join airlines airline1_ on submitteda0_.airline_id=airline1_.id where submitteda0_.user_id=?
Hibernate: select submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_1_, submitteda0_.airline_id as airline_2_1_1_, submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_1_, airline1_.id as id1_0_2_, airline1_.description as descript2_0_2_, airline1_.title as title3_0_2_ from applications submitteda0_ left outer join airlines airline1_ on submitteda0_.airline_id=airline1_.id where submitteda0_.user_id=?
Hibernate: select submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_1_, submitteda0_.airline_id as airline_2_1_1_, submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_1_, airline1_.id as id1_0_2_, airline1_.description as descript2_0_2_, airline1_.title as title3_0_2_ from applications submitteda0_ left outer join airlines airline1_ on submitteda0_.airline_id=airline1_.id where submitteda0_.user_id=?
Hibernate: select submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_1_, submitteda0_.airline_id as airline_2_1_1_, submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_1_, airline1_.id as id1_0_2_, airline1_.description as descript2_0_2_, airline1_.title as title3_0_2_ from applications submitteda0_ left outer join airlines airline1_ on submitteda0_.airline_id=airline1_.id where submitteda0_.user_id=?
Hibernate: select submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_1_, submitteda0_.airline_id as airline_2_1_1_, submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_1_, airline1_.id as id1_0_2_, airline1_.description as descript2_0_2_, airline1_.title as title3_0_2_ from applications submitteda0_ left outer join airlines airline1_ on submitteda0_.airline_id=airline1_.id where submitteda0_.user_id=?
Hibernate: select submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_1_, submitteda0_.airline_id as airline_2_1_1_, submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_1_, airline1_.id as id1_0_2_, airline1_.description as descript2_0_2_, airline1_.title as title3_0_2_ from applications submitteda0_ left outer join airlines airline1_ on submitteda0_.airline_id=airline1_.id where submitteda0_.user_id=?
Hibernate: select submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_1_, submitteda0_.airline_id as airline_2_1_1_, submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_1_, airline1_.id as id1_0_2_, airline1_.description as descript2_0_2_, airline1_.title as title3_0_2_ from applications submitteda0_ left outer join airlines airline1_ on submitteda0_.airline_id=airline1_.id where submitteda0_.user_id=?
Hibernate: select submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_1_, submitteda0_.airline_id as airline_2_1_1_, submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_1_, airline1_.id as id1_0_2_, airline1_.description as descript2_0_2_, airline1_.title as title3_0_2_ from applications submitteda0_ left outer join airlines airline1_ on submitteda0_.airline_id=airline1_.id where submitteda0_.user_id=?
Hibernate: select submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_1_, submitteda0_.airline_id as airline_2_1_1_, submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_1_, airline1_.id as id1_0_2_, airline1_.description as descript2_0_2_, airline1_.title as title3_0_2_ from applications submitteda0_ left outer join airlines airline1_ on submitteda0_.airline_id=airline1_.id where submitteda0_.user_id=?
Hibernate: select submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_1_, submitteda0_.airline_id as airline_2_1_1_, submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_1_, airline1_.id as id1_0_2_, airline1_.description as descript2_0_2_, airline1_.title as title3_0_2_ from applications submitteda0_ left outer join airlines airline1_ on submitteda0_.airline_id=airline1_.id where submitteda0_.user_id=?
Hibernate: select submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_1_, submitteda0_.airline_id as airline_2_1_1_, submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_1_, airline1_.id as id1_0_2_, airline1_.description as descript2_0_2_, airline1_.title as title3_0_2_ from applications submitteda0_ left outer join airlines airline1_ on submitteda0_.airline_id=airline1_.id where submitteda0_.user_id=?
Hibernate: select submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_1_, submitteda0_.airline_id as airline_2_1_1_, submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_1_, airline1_.id as id1_0_2_, airline1_.description as descript2_0_2_, airline1_.title as title3_0_2_ from applications submitteda0_ left outer join airlines airline1_ on submitteda0_.airline_id=airline1_.id where submitteda0_.user_id=?
Hibernate: select submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_1_, submitteda0_.airline_id as airline_2_1_1_, submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_1_, airline1_.id as id1_0_2_, airline1_.description as descript2_0_2_, airline1_.title as title3_0_2_ from applications submitteda0_ left outer join airlines airline1_ on submitteda0_.airline_id=airline1_.id where submitteda0_.user_id=?
Hibernate: select submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_1_, submitteda0_.airline_id as airline_2_1_1_, submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_1_, airline1_.id as id1_0_2_, airline1_.description as descript2_0_2_, airline1_.title as title3_0_2_ from applications submitteda0_ left outer join airlines airline1_ on submitteda0_.airline_id=airline1_.id where submitteda0_.user_id=?
Hibernate: select submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_1_, submitteda0_.airline_id as airline_2_1_1_, submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_1_, airline1_.id as id1_0_2_, airline1_.description as descript2_0_2_, airline1_.title as title3_0_2_ from applications submitteda0_ left outer join airlines airline1_ on submitteda0_.airline_id=airline1_.id where submitteda0_.user_id=?
Hibernate: select submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_1_, submitteda0_.airline_id as airline_2_1_1_, submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_1_, airline1_.id as id1_0_2_, airline1_.description as descript2_0_2_, airline1_.title as title3_0_2_ from applications submitteda0_ left outer join airlines airline1_ on submitteda0_.airline_id=airline1_.id where submitteda0_.user_id=?
Hibernate: select submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_1_, submitteda0_.airline_id as airline_2_1_1_, submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_1_, airline1_.id as id1_0_2_, airline1_.description as descript2_0_2_, airline1_.title as title3_0_2_ from applications submitteda0_ left outer join airlines airline1_ on submitteda0_.airline_id=airline1_.id where submitteda0_.user_id=?
Hibernate: select submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_1_, submitteda0_.airline_id as airline_2_1_1_, submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_1_, airline1_.id as id1_0_2_, airline1_.description as descript2_0_2_, airline1_.title as title3_0_2_ from applications submitteda0_ left outer join airlines airline1_ on submitteda0_.airline_id=airline1_.id where submitteda0_.user_id=?
Hibernate: select submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_1_, submitteda0_.airline_id as airline_2_1_1_, submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_1_, airline1_.id as id1_0_2_, airline1_.description as descript2_0_2_, airline1_.title as title3_0_2_ from applications submitteda0_ left outer join airlines airline1_ on submitteda0_.airline_id=airline1_.id where submitteda0_.user_id=?
Hibernate: select submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_1_, submitteda0_.airline_id as airline_2_1_1_, submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_1_, airline1_.id as id1_0_2_, airline1_.description as descript2_0_2_, airline1_.title as title3_0_2_ from applications submitteda0_ left outer join airlines airline1_ on submitteda0_.airline_id=airline1_.id where submitteda0_.user_id=?
Hibernate: select submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_1_, submitteda0_.airline_id as airline_2_1_1_, submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_1_, airline1_.id as id1_0_2_, airline1_.description as descript2_0_2_, airline1_.title as title3_0_2_ from applications submitteda0_ left outer join airlines airline1_ on submitteda0_.airline_id=airline1_.id where submitteda0_.user_id=?
Hibernate: select submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_1_, submitteda0_.airline_id as airline_2_1_1_, submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_1_, airline1_.id as id1_0_2_, airline1_.description as descript2_0_2_, airline1_.title as title3_0_2_ from applications submitteda0_ left outer join airlines airline1_ on submitteda0_.airline_id=airline1_.id where submitteda0_.user_id=?
Hibernate: select submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_0_, submitteda0_.id as id1_1_1_, submitteda0_.airline_id as airline_2_1_1_, submitteda0_.user_id as user_id3_1_1_, airline1_.id as id1_0_2_, airline1_.description as descript2_0_2_, airline1_.title as title3_0_2_ from applications submitteda0_ left outer join airlines airline1_ on submitteda0_.airline_id=airline1_.id where submitteda0_.user_id=?
```

Until I come across this:

```
2020-04-27 19:11:53.376 ERROR 4344 --- [0.4-8080-exec-5] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Application exception overridden by rollback exception

java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:369) ~[postgresql-42.2.11.jar:42.2.11]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:159) ~[postgresql-42.2.11.jar:42.2.11]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:109) ~[postgresql-42.2.11.jar:42.2.11]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
```

How can I fix this?

Airline.java

```java
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "airlines")
public class Airline {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "airline",  cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Application> applications = new HashSet<>(); //Applied user applications, also includes exams
}
```

Application.java

```java
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "applications")
public class Application {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user; //User submitted applied

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "airline_id")
    private Airline airline; //Airline applied to

    public Application() {
    }
}
```

Relation in User.java

```java
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Application> submittedApplications = new HashSet<>();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not because of Hibernate but becasue of your Lombok annotations:

```
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
```

You have to be careful when using these annotations that you don't get infinite loops. If you call for example toString() on entity1, then toString() on entity2 is called which calls again toString() on entity1 etc..

Either remove these annotations if you are not really using them, or configure them in a way, that no infinite loops occur.

Comment: this worked, but I also needed to add the `@JsonIgnore` so the response wouldn't be 5000 lines long